# onfocus not working (triggering) in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg, cross-browser

With this HTML:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

and the following JS:

```
document.getElementById("circle").onfocus = function(){
    console.log("focused");
}
```

Then in Chrome and Edge, clicking on (or otherwise focusing on) the circle logs "focused" to the console. However, in Firefox nothing happens.

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ss8z9tnp/) with the code.

What cause this issue and how can it be rectified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a tabindex to the element which you need to trigger focus

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle tabindex="0" id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
</svg>
```

then

```
document.getElementById("circle").onfocus = function(){
    console.log("focused");
}
```